# How to update Rectangle collider when rotating a sprite

Tags: c#, math, xna, rotation

Before you mention, I know there are alot of other questions like this on this site, however there is only one that I can find for XNA. I don't really understand any of them completely.

Basically what occurs is when I rotate my sprite, the paddle and ball still collide even when the paddle has been rotated. I am assuming this is due to the bounding box not being updated.

Also when I rotate the paddle, there is no reference in terms of no degrees that it is rotating, well of course there is in theory but in the actual program I would like to print to screen the degrees the paddle has rotated, therefore I would need an initial value of 0 when the paddle is either facing up or when it's horizontal.

I have looked at matrices, etc (using Google, so you can't say to go look on Google) but I'm unsure of how to use matrices in my case. I mean I would need to rotate the bounding box using a rotation matrix and then somehow update the bounding box position, so I would need to convert the matrix result into a `Vector2`? Also I don't know what this result should be assigned as, (the box's X value, sorry I'm doing RUBBISH)

If any of this makes sense and anyone can help that would be great. Thanks very much!

Oh, I should include the code, that would be slightly helpful:

```
float pRotationSpeed;
float circle = MathHelper.Pi * 2;
float RotationAngle;
float RotationAngledegrees;

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    RotationAngle %= circle;
    RotationAngledegrees = MathHelper.ToDegrees(RotationAngle);

    pRectangle = new Rectangle((int)pPosition.X, (int)pPosition.Y, pWidth, pHeight);

    HandleInput();
}

public void HandleInput()
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        pRotationSpeed -= 0.1f;
        RotationAngledegrees = (float)Math.Cos(pRotationSpeed);
    }

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        pRotationSpeed += 0.1f;
        RotationAngledegrees = (float)Math.Cos(pRotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

Oh by the way, for the `rotationAngle`, etc I was messing around, so that code probably will be deleted, I mean if you advice it. (as I don't really understand it, just experimenting and trying to get some output to screen).

EDIT:

```
public void CalcVertices()
{
    Vertex.Add(new Vector2(0, 0)); //top-left corner.
    Vertex.Add(new Vector2(pRectangle.Width, 0)); //top-right corner.
    Vertex.Add(new Vector2(0, pRectangle.Height)); //bottom-left corner.
    Vertex.Add(new Vector2(pRectangle.Width, pRectangle.Height)); //bottom-right corner.

    rotVertex.Add(new Vector2((0 * Math.Cos(rotAngle)) - (0 * Math.Sin(rotAngle))); 
}
```

Comment: Bounding boxes in XNA are axis-aligned (AABB), which means they never have any rotation. You can create a bounding box that fully contains your rotated paddle, but that's probably not what you want, since it will be much larger than the paddle itself when the paddle rotates. You'll need to do the collision detection yourself.

Comment: Oh ok, i did keep coming across AABB... and someone did mention in other post's about axis-aligned. I suppose it's not so bad that i didn't know how to rotate a bounding box... lol if it cant be done OR can be but in a messy way... thanks for the quick response

Comment: What is the meaning of multiplying `Sin` and `Cos` by 0 in the last piece of code you've added? It will always be zero!

Comment: tip: if you scale your sprite bounding box remain same size. rotating and scaling does not affect bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

Your collision rectangle and the actual image are essentially separate objects to rotate individually. You would need to do some simple trigonometry on the 4 points of the rectangle to figure out their new positions after rotation.

To do this: Convert each vertex into a vector from the center of the rectangle(or rather, translate that rotation point to the origin). Then, for each of your corner points (represented [x,y]) you can rotate them using simple trig. To do this, the formula is:

```
new_x = (old_x * cos(rot_angle)) - (old_y * sin(rot_angle));
new_y = (old_y * cos(rot_angle)) + (old_x * sin(rot_angle));
```

Once you have the new verts, translate the rectangle's center back to its original position.

Edit: This is assuming your collision bounds do not have to be axis-aligned. Whether or not this works depends on how you are handling collisions.

Comment: Hi. Thanks v much for the post... tbh i don't really understand what you meant by convert each vertex into a vector from the 'center of the rectangle'... (sorry... :( ). I will update my main post above with the code i have added using your way... :) thanks .... (Also tbh, i don't even know what the rotAngle that i have in my code is, i mean i copied it from a post on here i think just to experiment with stuff...)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I got a bit mathy there.

A 'vertex' is just another name for one of the corners of the rectangle. Converting a vertex into a vector is the same thing as moving the center of the rectangle to the origin(0,0). If you were to draw an arrow from 0,0 to every vertex, each of those arrows would be a 'vector'.

Vectors can be 2D, like yours, or 3D with x,y, and z coordinates. This is how we represent points in space in computing, and through a lot of rules it makes it easy to do math on them. Here's a great starting tutorial: http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vectorindex.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yea dw i knew what a vertex was and a bit about vectors but i do appreciate your help... i will read through the link you have provided... thanks again :)